# Bloqueo al utilizar AJAX haciendo multiples consultas a MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

No pude determinar un buen título para mi problema pero es el siguiente, estoy haciendo una pequeña página para hacer consultas a una base de datos, la idea es que mientras el usuario escriba en un input se vayan mostrando los resultados en una tabla, para eso estoy implementado AJAX, un servidor MySQL remoto y PHP, ejecutando la página desde mi PC corre muy bien, al momento de escribir busca los datos en el servidor remoto y los muestra al momento, el problema es que subí dicha página a un hosting de paga y ahí al momento de escribir, después de hacer unas cuantas consultas se bloquea y ya no busca nada, imagino que ha de ser por la velocidad o algo así, pero no encuentro una forma de optimizar mi código, espero me puedan ayudar. Les adjunto mi página para que hagan las pruebas: www.oaxaqueando.com solo busquen nombres de personas y notarán que se bloquea y ya no busca, el código lo pongo a continuación:

```js
function buscar_datos(consulta)
{
$.ajax({
 url: 'buscar.php',
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'html',
 data: {consulta: consulta},
})

.done(function(respuesta) {
 $("#datos").html(respuesta);
})
}

$(document).on('keydown','#caja_busqueda',function(){
   var valor =  $(this).val();
         buscar_datos(valor);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda">                              
            </div>
            <div id="datos">              
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
                  
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

$buscar = str_replace(" ", "%", $_POST['consulta']);
$salida = "";

if ($buscar != "") {

$mysqli = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "bd");
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

$query = "SELECT * FROM bd_secjo.contactos where concat(nombres, ' ', apellido_paterno, ' ', apellido_materno) like '%" . $buscar . "%' limit 10;";

$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

    $salida = "<table class='tabla_datos'>
       <thead>
            <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>";

    while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $salida = $salida . "<tr>" .
                "<td>". $fila['Nombres'] . "</td>" .
                "<td>". $fila['Apellido_Paterno'] . "</td>" .
                "<td>". $fila['Apellido_Materno'] . "</td>" ;
    }

    $salida = $salida . "</tbody></table>";

} else {
    $salida = "Sin resultados";
}

$mysqli->close();

}


echo $salida;
```

Utilizo Windows 7, MySQL, Hosting de Godaddy de 1 CPU, 512mb de RAM

Comment: De entrada deberías usar PDO porque mysqli está sujeto a inyecciones SQL y deprecado en versiones nuevas de PHP, y en segunda solo deberías regresar el resultado de la consulta como json al cliente, y que JS se encargue de hacer la tabla, o incluso ten la tabla ya construída, y solo carga los datos, así acelerarás aún más el proceso

Answer (score 1):

No soy un hacha en optimización y no he montado un escenario de prueba para probar tu ejemplo, pero el mayor problema que estoy viendo en tu código es que relegas demasiado trabajo en el PHP al que llamas por AJAX.

Date cuenta que por cada vez que se pulse una tecla se lanza la llamada y el sistema se queda esperando a que el PHP le construya la respuesta, en este caso que recorra lo que recupera de la base de datos y construya una tabla. Y piensa que mientras está haciendo esto, el usuario pulsará otra tecla y es posible que no se haya terminado de construir la respuesta de la anterior petición por entonces.

Personalmente, me gusta devolver en mis llamadas AJAX objetos JSON y que sea el lado del cliente el que se ocupe de "pintar" el HTML. En tú código, con eso liberarías bastante trabajo al servidor, que tratándose de un hostin el pobrete, no va tan rápido como puede llegar a escribir una persona en tu caja de búsqueda.

Un saludo y espero que te ayude.

Comment: Genial, voy a intentarlo así, la verdad es que sí, he notado que el PHP es el que se está sobrecargando pero no había pensando en traer los datos al cliente en formato JSON. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Mira yo en mi sitio www.glosarioit.com hago uso de JQuery y en especial del controlador Autocomplete. También utilizo PHP y AJAX, pero le agrego JQuery.

Como podrás ver cuando quieres buscar un término en el campo de búsqueda se va mostrando según la coincidencia. Tengo más de 6000 definiciones cargadas en MySQL y no se produce retardo alguno.
Espero te sirva, sobre todo, de referencia.

Comment: Según entiendo que tendría que cargar todos mis datos en el lado del cliente, para que después mediante Autocomplete los recorra y vaya mostrando las coincidencias, es así?

Comment: Claro. Yo por ejemplo tengo la consulta de MySQL en PHP y luego desde JavaScript hago: 
_var sql = new Array(<?php echo $sArray?>);_
Después en la variable _sql_ tengo almacenado cada término que esta en el Array entre comillas dobles ("") y separados por coma (,).